# not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in php

Tags: php, mysql

I try connect my remote server database in php but it's give bellow error

`Host 'xx.xxx.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in`

My connection code like this

```
$servername = "my_server_address";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$dbname = "my_db";    
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: This is not a PHP issue, but a MariaDB security/access issue. Please improve the question by providing more information about your MariaDB security configuration and any other ways you've tried connecting.

Comment: Have managed to solve this? i also faced identical warning though using mysql but got maria db error.

Answer (score 4):

If your credentials are valid, you most likely need to configure MariaDB for remote client access.

See [Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)

Comment: Thank for your response , I already try with this but it's not working for me

Comment: @yashvantzala Alternatively this could be your user doesn't have permission to connect to the database. Can you connect to the database with an ordinary sql client (like HeidiSQL)?

Comment: i think it's other issue because same configuration working in my ubuntu pc but not working in window pc. and i try with mysql workbench but it's give same error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after installing "xampp-windows-x64-7.3.6". After looking around and testing several solutions without any changes I did the following:

- Uninstall xampp
- Restart machine
- Reinstall xampp
- Restart machine
- Importing old databases via phpmyadmin

All works fine for me now.

I did initially add a new user account. That might have caused the problem but I'm not testing this again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new user in mariadb, goto privileges and add that can be accessed remotely

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.