# How do I allow connection to the MariaDB?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am a mac user and so only have access to the mac terminal.

I am developing a database driven website, I'm trying to connect to the database but keep getting this error which I don't know how to fix.

My php code is:

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect("MY IP ADDRESS HERE","root","","coursework")
```

but when opening the browser I get the following message:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '192.168.64.2' is not
>   allowed to connect to this MariaDB server in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/functions/db.php on line 2

Does anybody know how I can allow connection to this database? Thank you in advance

Comment: I've never used MariaDB but a Google search for your error came up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124641/not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mariadb-server-in-php

Comment: maybe your ip-address is not given in the configuration of your sever and/or the option _bind-address_ is set so that your connection can't be established using your IP. try it with _localhost_ instead or check your configuration file of MariaDB (which should be my.cnf somewhere on your system; e.g. /etc/) for that issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a security precaution. You could try adding a new administrator account:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have necessary permission to access your database through a script. You need to open up connection to your database. Use the following SQL query and execute it.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON coursework.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

- coursework.* means all tables of database 'coursework'.
- root@'%' means access to root coming from any IP.
- Replace password with your MySQL password.

*Side note: Don't use root to access MySQL server from PHP. Create a user instead. Hope it helps.*